# Replacing pixels by custom images in Mathematica?

Tags: image, image-processing, wolfram-mathematica

How can I replace the pixels of a binarized image with a custom image in Mathematica?
I figured that once I have a matrix M of 0 or 1 entries depending on a pixel being white or black (which I can obtain by using Binarize and manipulating the output a bit), I can use Graphics[] to place a custom image with square boundary in a grid wherever there's a 1 and a flat background when there's a 0, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `M` is your matrix containing 0's and 1's and `image0/image1` are the images you want to display:

```
image0 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10];
image1 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 10];
M = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}};
```

You can just do this:

```
GraphicsGrid[M /. {0 -> image0, 1 -> image1}]
```

[image]

or, if you want the 0's to be blank:

```
GraphicsGrid[M /. {0 -> "", 1 -> image1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
mat = RandomInteger[1, {10, 10}];
Graphics[MapIndexed[If[#1 == 1, Disk, Circle][#2, 0.4] &, mat, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I like to use various versions of `MapIndexed` for this.  Instead of `Disk` or `Circle` you can use any other graphics object.  Just make a function that will take a position as its argument and will produce that object.